# JPanel is resized if it is larger than its parent

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JScrollPanel`, I add a `JPanel` containing an image to the `JScrollPanel` and it works, but if the image within the `JPanel` is larger that the `JScrollPanel` either in width, height, or both the panel is then resized to about 20x20. Why is it doing that? I am using the `GridBagLayout` on the viewport of the `JScrollPanel`. What I am expecting is that if the `JPanel` is larger than the `JScrollPanel` it will add scroll bars, but that isn't what is happening. Any suggestions?

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    WebFileChooser wfc = null;
    if(wfc == null){
        wfc = new WebFileChooser(this, "Open an Image");
        wfc.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        wfc.setAvailableFilter(GlobalConstants.IMAGES_AND_FOLDERS_FILTER);
        wfc.setChooseFilter(GlobalConstants.IMAGES_FILTER);
        wfc.setCurrentDirectory("/Users/Ryan/Desktop");
    }
    wfc.setVisible(true);

    if(wfc.getResult() == StyleConstants.OK_OPTION){
        String file = wfc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        try{
            imagePane.remove(canvas);
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setVisible(true);
        canvas.setImage(file);
        //imagePane.getViewport().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        canvas.setSizeFromLoaded();
        imagePane.getViewport().add(canvas);
        imagePane.repaint();
        imagePane.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Here is the Canvas Class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pocketshop;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import pocketshop.util.ImageSync;

/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class Canvas extends CanvasShadow{

    public static BufferedImage image = null, preview = null;
    public static int width, height;

    public void setImage(String filename){
        try{
            Canvas.image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
            Canvas.width = image.getWidth();
            Canvas.height = image.getHeight();
            ImageSync.originalPixels = new int[width * height];
            ImageSync.previewPixels = new int[width * height];
            Canvas.image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, ImageSync.originalPixels, 0, width);
        }catch(IOException e){
        }
    }

    public static void setImage(BufferedImage image){
        Canvas.image = image;
        Canvas.width = image.getWidth();
        Canvas.height = image.getHeight();
        ImageSync.originalPixels = new int[width * height];
        ImageSync.previewPixels = new int[width * height];
        Canvas.image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, ImageSync.originalPixels, 0, width);
    }

    public static void setPreview(BufferedImage img, Container parent){
        preview = img;
        parent.repaint();
    }

    public static BufferedImage deepCopy(){
        ColorModel cm = Canvas.image.getColorModel();
        boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
        WritableRaster raster = Canvas.image.copyData(null);
        return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
    }

    public void setSizeFromLoaded(){
        try{
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Canvas.width + 10, Canvas.height + 10));
            this.setSize(Canvas.width + 10, Canvas.height + 10);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(Canvas.preview != null){
            g.drawImage(Canvas.preview, 5, 5, width, height, Color.black, null);
        }else{
            g.drawImage(Canvas.image, 5, 5, width, height, Color.black, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the CanvasShadow Class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pocketshop;

import java.awt.Color;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXPanel;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.border.DropShadowBorder;

public class CanvasShadow extends JXPanel{

    public CanvasShadow(){
        DropShadowBorder shadow = new DropShadowBorder();
        shadow.setShadowColor(Color.BLACK);
        shadow.setShowLeftShadow(true);
        shadow.setShowRightShadow(true);
        shadow.setShowBottomShadow(true);
        shadow.setShowTopShadow(true);
        this.setBorder(shadow);

        float[] hsb = new float[3];

        Color.RGBtoHSB(255, 255, 255, hsb);

        this.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]));
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the actual image: http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/4800000/Beach-beaches-4843817-1280-800.jpg

Comment: Well I guess I should be careful what I asked for.  Dude what's up with all of the statics?!  Get rid of them.  You just created a reusable panel that can't be instantiated more than once because all instances of Canvas share the same image.  Instance variables are your friend.  Statics are the devil!!  What is this ImageSync thing?  More statics?!

Comment: Don't use remove().  Just set the file on the existing canvas instance.  It will redraw using the new image.

Comment: If I got rid of the statics, how would I access the class from another class that can't overwrite the data, for example a dialog box that has adjustment sliders to adjust the image's brightness.

Comment: Just have an instance reference to that class. For example, if Canvas needs to talk to ImageSync then Canvas would have an instance variable of type ImageSync. The client constructing Canvas will provide the ImageSync instance to the Canvas instance upon construction or by calling a setter method. I'm not sure why Canvas has a dependency on ImageSync because you can do this without it, but as an example that's what you'd do. It's called a dependency when one object has a reference to another object. Your Canvas object has a dependency with BufferedImage too...

Comment: It's best to let the client provide the dependencies an object requires if it doesn't manage the lifetime of those dependencies.  Using statics as a way to find instances of other objects locks you down so you can't ever have more than ONE instance of a given object.  You may only need one instance today, but as requirements change you might need two or more.  If you don't use statics creating another instance is 1 minute of work. With statics it can be days of refactoring before it will work.  If you only need one instance call new once, and pass it around to your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already told you get rid of that GridBagLayout.  Setting the layout on the JScrollPane will resize the panel so it's never bigger than the container.  You're panel has to lay itself out so that it's the size of the the image in order for the JScrollPane to see it's too big to display.  It's only then does JScrollPane add the scrollbars.  So if your image is 2000x2000 then your panel needs to set it's preferred size to 2000x2000 and act like it can be that big.  The JScrollPane will do all of the heavy lifting to crop and make sure the panel only renders the portion visible based on the scroll bars.  If your panel is always the same size as the viewport of the JScrollPane then the scroll pane thinks it fits and there is no need for scroll bars.

**Update**: Quick google search revealed the answer:  http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=168

Comment: I removed `GridBagLayout` and it works, but now the scroll bars are not there and the JPanel is no longer in the center of the JScrollPanel.

Comment: What does it mean that the JPanel is not in the center?  Where is the image?  How big is the image you are displaying vs how big the JScrollPane's viewport is?  Are you overriding paintComponent() on JPanel to manually draw the image on the panel or are you doing something else?

Comment: Okay, I have added some source code. The image displays in the top left corner. The CanvasShadow displays the full height and width of the scrollpanel. I'll attach two screen shots to the main question.

Comment: That's because you are drawing it in the top left corner.  You can override getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() and getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() to return false and your component won't track it's size to the size of the view port.  As for centering it when it's smaller than the visible area.  You could try and use setHorizontalAlignment() and setVerticalAlignment() and see if ScrollPaneLayout will pay attention to those.  If that doesn't work you'll have to subclass ScrollPaneLayout to center your component when it's smaller than the size of viewport.

Comment: Sweet! Here is what I added: canvas.setScrollableTracksViewportHeight(false);
canvas.setScrollableTracksViewportWidth(false);

Comment: Updated the answer with the centering fix.